# Getting `sqlstate` code from exception in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get sqlslate code from an exception object like:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near xx at line 1 in xx.
```

I am using following code:

```
 var_dump("code is: ".$exception->getCode());
```

but it returns `0`. How can I get the code like 420000.

Comment: Is that significant? I am trying to get sql code from exception.

Comment: `errorCode()`  and/or `errorInfo` for PDO or `sqlstate()` for mysqli.